# How can I get the Date from year and how much total days have passed?

Tags: javascript

I have two variables,

```
let year = 2003;
let passedDays = 275;
```

I need to get the `Date` as  `2003-10-02` from those two variables.
How can I do it without writing a hundred lines of if statements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build a `date` object with the given year, for January, the first, then add the needed days :

```js
let year = 2003;
let passedDays = 275;

// note that months starts with zero
//                        |
//                        V
let date = new Date(year, 0, 1);
// Make sure passedDays is a number, not a string containing a number,
// otherwise you'll get wrong result (string concat)
//                            |
//                            V
date.setDate(date.getDate() + +passedDays);

console.log(date);
```

Comment: It works great here, but when I implemented it to my script, it said Oct 3 instead of Oct 2.
`let date = new Date(year, 0, 0);`. So I changed the day `1` to `0`. Now it works great in the script too. My edit won't cause any other errors will it ?

Comment: As far as I know, no it won't. The day 0 is the last day of the previous month

Comment: Oh, wait, this shouldn't be the case, using `new Date(year, 0, 1);` should give you the correct result. This could be due to some timezone issues

Comment: I thought so too, My time zone is GMT+0530.